# Facebook Android Automatic In-App Purchase Logging Data Error

Tags: in-app, facebook-analytics

I used facebook Android SDK(verison 4.28) for Automatic In-App Purchase Logging, I add the code follow the [DOC](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/app-events/android?locale=en_US)

my code is :

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    // Pass on the activity result to the helper for handling
    if (!mInAppBillingManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)) {
        // not handled, so handle it ourselves (here's where you'd
        // perform any handling of activity results not related to in-app
        // billing...
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }
    if (requestCode == 10001) {
        CallbackManager callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();
        callbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }
}
```

but the In-App Purchase Data is wrong. Help me please

Comment: Can you elaborate--what exactly is wrong?

Comment: ok，for examle, the Facebook Analutics dashboard shows there are 3 people cost 1000$ for buying. this is more than the google play And GA data

Comment: If you put this info in the question, it will become more useful and easier to answer.